# Flutter: setState for external widget

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

In the default new flutter project, there is floatingActionButton.
I want this to be in external file/widget but having trouble with setState()

Is this possible?  Thanks

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the _incrementCounter method down to the other widget.

File 1:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: IncrementCounterButton(
        incrementCounter: _incrementCounter,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

File 2:

```
class IncrementCounterButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() incrementCounter;

  IncrementCounterButton({Key key, this.incrementCounter) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this work.  Initially have "error: 'key' isn't a field in the enclosing class."  so I add   "final key;" to define it.  It is the correct way?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, try removing the key field from the class and change `this.key` to `Key key` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function instead of calling it. The code:

```
onPressed: () { _incrementCounter(); },
```

or like this of you like shortcuts:

```
onPressed: () => _incrementCounter(),
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)

Comment: Hi.  The previous solution is correct but for learning purpose, how to pass the function? Please share detail solution. Thanks